# how to `gain access to the mobile Uber site`? error with Deep linking for Mobile Web

Tags: uber-api

I am following the docs for deep linking here:

https://developer.uber.com/v1/deep-linking/#launching-the-uber-mobile-site

Well, I can open the site, and I choose login, I typed my password and press return, and I see this:

> Please download the Uber app or visit http://t.uber.com/support to request access to the mobile Uber site.

I don't even know what it means. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because Uber wants your app to open the Uber app and not the mobile site. The mobile site is available for users who cannot get the Uber app to work - but a user must request access to it.

Users can request access to the mobile site here: https://help.uber.com/h/1ed2c9ac-daad-4413-91ee-09c8aefec8da

I honestly don't know why it's not open to the public by default... and why Uber links don't automatically open the Uber app. I feel like there's a design flaw with this, because web apps can't open the Uber app via the Uber URL.

[An intent filter could have been added that catches the URL and opens the App.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

***Overall, and at the time of this writing, Uber is still very buggy.***